# What's the most efficient way to calculate daily active users leveraging the rails ahoy and groupdate gems?

Tags: sql, ruby-on-rails, postgresql, activerecord

I'm using the [Ahoy](https://github.com/ankane/ahoy) (https://github.com/ankane/ahoy.js) gem for analytics. I'd like to calculate daily active users. The current SQL query that I have is based on the [GroupDate](https://github.com/ankane/groupdate) documentation. Given the table `ahoy_visits`, which has columns `started_at` and `user_id`. It calculates the number of visits per day.

```
SELECT date_trunc('day', started_at)::date AS day, COUNT(*) AS visits FROM ahoy_visits GROUP BY day ORDER BY day
```

The problem is that it double counts visits from the same user on the same day. I only want to count one visit per day per user. Is there an easy way to modify this query to accomplish that goal?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You want `count(distinct)`:

```
SELECT date_trunc('day', started_at)::date AS day, COUNT(DISTINCT user_id) AS visits
FROM ahoy_visits
GROUP BY day
ORDER BY day
```

Comment: Thanks! This is exactly what I was looking for.